# Where is the tunnel man in Spelunky for Xbox 360?

Tags: spelunky-hd

I am playing the game with two people and we never meet the tunnel man in between levels. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

There is no tunnel man in multiplayer. You can only progress through the story in single player.